# how to Insert Calorie data into googlefit app using android code

Tags: android, google-fit

Following code is for insert calories data into googlefit app, same like this code perfectly working for steps data insertion in googlefit app but not working for calories and showing different calories value in googlefit app.
Please help me out for this.

```
   Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date now = new Date();
    cal.setTime(now);
    long endTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
    cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, -1);
    long startTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();

    // Create a data source
    DataSource dataSource = new DataSource.Builder()
            .setAppPackageName(context)
            .setDataType(DataType.TYPE_CALORIES_EXPENDED)
            .setStreamName(TAG + " - Calorie")
            .setType(DataSource.TYPE_RAW)
            .build();

    // Create a data set
    int CalDelta = 50;
    DataSet dataSet = DataSet.create(dataSource);
    // For each data point, specify a start time, end time, and the data     value -- in this case,
    // the number of new steps.
    DataPoint dataPoint = dataSet.createDataPoint()
            .setTimeInterval(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    dataPoint.getValue(Field.FIELD_CALORIES).setFloat(CalDelta);
    dataSet.add(dataPoint);
```

Answer (score 1):

To insert data on Google fit app, you'll be working with [Fitness History](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/history#insert_data).

> First create a Data set instance:

```
// Set a start and end time for our data, using a start time of 1 hour before this moment.
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
Date now = new Date();
cal.setTime(now);
long endTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, -1);
long startTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();

// Create a data source
DataSource dataSource = new DataSource.Builder()
        .setAppPackageName(this)
        .setDataType(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
        .setStreamName(TAG + " - step count")
        .setType(DataSource.TYPE_RAW)
        .build();

// Create a data set
int stepCountDelta = 950;
DataSet dataSet = DataSet.create(dataSource);
// For each data point, specify a start time, end time, and the data value -- in this case,
// the number of new steps.
DataPoint dataPoint = dataSet.createDataPoint()
        .setTimeInterval(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
dataPoint.getValue(Field.FIELD_STEPS).setInt(stepCountDelta);
dataSet.add(dataPoint);
```

> After you create a DataSet instance, use the HistoryApi.insertData
>   method and wait synchronously or provide a callback method to check
>   the status of the insertion.

```
// Then, invoke the History API to insert the data and await the result, which is
// possible here because of the {@link AsyncTask}. Always include a timeout when calling
// await() to prevent hanging that can occur from the service being shutdown because
// of low memory or other conditions.
Log.i(TAG, "Inserting the dataset in the History API.");
com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status insertStatus =
        Fitness.HistoryApi.insertData(mClient, dataSet)
                .await(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

// Before querying the data, check to see if the insertion succeeded.
if (!insertStatus.isSuccess()) {
    Log.i(TAG, "There was a problem inserting the dataset.");
    return null;
}

// At this point, the data has been inserted and can be read.
Log.i(TAG, "Data insert was successful!");
```

Comment: Thanks for replay.

Comment: Above code working for steps but i want to add the CALORIES data into googlefit

Answer (score 1):

```
private DataSet getCaloriesDataSet(float killoCalories) {

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    Date now = new Date();
    cal.setTime(now);
    long endTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
    cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, -1);
    long startTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();

    // Create a data source
    DataSource dataSource = new DataSource.Builder()
            .setAppPackageName("com.your.fitness.app")
            .setDataType(DataType.TYPE_CALORIES_EXPENDED)
            .setType(DataSource.TYPE_RAW)
            .build();

    // Create a data set
    //  int stepCountDelta = 950;
    DataSet dataSet = DataSet.create(dataSource);
    // For each data point, specify a start time, end time, and the data value -- in this case,
    // the number of new steps.
    DataPoint dataPoint = dataSet.createDataPoint()
            .setTimeInterval(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    dataPoint.getValue(Field.FIELD_CALORIES).setFloat(killoCalories);

    dataSet.add(dataPoint);
    // [END build_insert_data_request]

    return dataSet;
}
```

After you have created the data set.

```
  DataSet calorieDataSet=getCaloriesDataSet(0.1f);
 com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status insertStatus =
    Fitness.HistoryApi.insertData(mClient, calorieDataSet)
            .await(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

Note : Set calories in killo. Lets you have 100 caloreis, then pass 100/1000=0.1 to this method. Otherwise Google fit api will through field out of range exception.